# wp_nav_menu_items not working for child theme

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I am developing the plugin in wordpress to add menu item using

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item',10,2);
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
        $items.="<li>Testing Menu</li>";
        return $items;
}
```

In parent theme it appends new menu item to current menu, the problem is its not working with child theme.
anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your function.php .

in wp-admin set menu Theme locations Top primary menu

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li> <a>Show whatever</a></li>';
    }
    //echo $items;

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: your_custom_menu_item is not being called. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code..
You forget to add this condition : `if ($args->theme_location == 'primary-menu')`

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2);

function your_custom_menu_item($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {
        $items.="<li>Testing Menu</li>";
        return $items;
    }
}
```

I hope its helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add `if ($args->theme_location == 'primary-menu')` condition.

Follow the following filter its works for me..

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item',10,2);
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
 if ($args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {
        $items.="<li>Testing Menu</li>";
        return $items;
}
}
```